# Нужнa помощь с sql запросом

Tags: postgresql

Ребят, есть такой вот запрос:

```
select kp,np,od,ei,svi,cp,cpn,cpuch,ocp,ocn,ocuch,ns,podr,prim,dz
                    from clippersql.ncpkisql                    
                    where (svi <= '14.06.2018')
                    and (kp = '' or '' = '')
                    and (np like '' or '' = '')
                    order by kp,svi desc
                    limit 100
```

В базе бывает так что значение полей `kp,np,od,ei` повторяются, можно ли как-то сделать так чтобы они повторялись всего один раз, а дальше если в поле такое же значение как и предыдущее оставлять его пустым, и посчитать сколько повторений в каждом поле?

Comment: Сделай, пожалуйста, синтетический пример данных и требуемого результата. Естественно, количество полей лучше разумно уменьшить.

Comment: *можно ли как-то сделать так чтобы они повторялись всего один раз* Да. *а дальше если в поле такое же значение как и предыдущее оставлять его пустым* Да, но нет. *посчитать сколько повторений в каждом поле* Сгруппировать и посчитать. Заодно и дубликаты уберутся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH select_part AS (
    SELECT kp, np, od, ei, svi, cp, cpn, cpuch, ocp, ocn, ocuch, ns, podr, prim, dz,
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY kp) AS kp_count, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY kp) AS kp_row, 
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY np) AS np_count, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY np) AS np_row, 
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY od) AS od_count, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY od) AS od_row, 
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ei) AS ei_count, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ei) AS ei_row
    FROM clippersql.ncpkisql                    
        WHERE svi <= '14.06.2018'
            AND (kp = '' or '' = '')
            AND (np LIKE '' OR '' = '')
            ORDER BY kp, svi DESC
            LIMIT 100)              
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN kp_row = 1 THEN kp ELSE null END AS kp, CASE WHEN kp_row=1 THEN kp_count ELSE null END AS kp_count,
    CASE WHEN np_row = 1 THEN np ELSE null END AS np, CASE WHEN np_row=1 THEN np_count ELSE null END AS np_count,
    CASE WHEN od_row = 1 THEN od ELSE null END AS od, CASE WHEN od_row=1 THEN od_count ELSE null END AS od_count,
    CASE WHEN ei_row = 1 THEN ei ELSE null END AS ei, CASE WHEN ei_row=1 THEN ei_count ELSE null END AS ei_count,
    svi, cp, cpn, cpuch, ocp, ocn, ocuch, ns, podr, prim, dz 
FROM select_part;
```